# Nsight Eclipse not found/CUDA11.1 installation problems

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-18.04, nvcc, nsight

I can't find Nsight Eclipse Edition after cuda installation.

I installed cuda11.1 on Ubuntu18.04(Nvidia Driver was installed before),and no error shows.
But when I input "nvcc -V",and "nsight" on terminal, it shows "command 'nvcc' not found","command 'nsight' not found". I solved the former problem by adding environment variables to ~/.bashrc.And in folder /usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin, I can't find executable file "nsight"(executable file of Nsight Eclipse Edition),which should have been there after cuda installation. Someone has met this before?

Comment: I am trying to find Nsight Eclipse Edition,not Nsight Compute!

Comment: There is no Nsight Eclipse Edition anymore. NVIDIA ship plugins for standard Eclipse for C++ instead. Again documentation here -- https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsightee-plugins-install-guide/index.html

Comment: Thanks! I saw Nsight Eclipse plugins in installation guide but I didn't realize that is the new IDE.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [CUDA 11 release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.0/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html):

> **CUDA Developer Tools**
>
> - Nsight Eclipse Edition standalone is dropped in CUDA 11.0.

There is no longer a standalone fork of Eclipse for the Nsight IDE. Instead plugins are shipped which run inside in the standard Eclipse IDE for C++. See here in the documentation for [installation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.0/nsightee-plugins-install-guide/index.html) and [use](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.0/nsight-eclipse-plugins-guide/index.html).

Comment: I just wanted to add a note that installing cuda will also install the nsightee plugin zip file.
as a result, you'll be able to find it in your local machine. In my case it is located in ==> `/usr/local/cuda-11.5/nsightee_plugins/com.nvidia.cuda.repo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip`. This file should be used inside of the eclipse ide